# Is there anyway that I can ask user to authenticate a specified account

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

We let users/companies add their facebook accounts to our system, and we let them authenticate those accounts after they are added, so that we can get details which are not public otherwise. so we need tell user which account to authenticate against, is this possible ?
Lets say user is already logged into facebook with account x, then he logins to our app and choose to authenticate account Y, so he will click on the authenticate link for Y and proceed to authenticate, is there anyway to enfore user to authenticate Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the solution was, first check if user is already logged into facebook, and logout them  using  FB.logout. Then open the login dialog (FB.login) so that they can log into the desired account. On successful login, check that the logged in user is same as the link that was clicked on.

The overall code is some thing like this

```
$('.fb-login').live('click', function() {
    var accountName = $(this).attr('id');

    //if user is already logged in, logout him so that he can authenticate correct account
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
              FB.logout(function(resp) {
                  console.log("Logged out of facebook")
                });                 
          }
    }, true);

    FB.login(function(response) {
         if (response.authResponse) {
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                console.log(response);
                console.log('Fetching FB account information.... ');                   
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                   console.log('Account name, ' + response.username + '.');                    
                   //validate that user authenticated the same account as the link he clicked on
                   if(accountName == response.username || accountName == response.id) {
                     //save token
                   } else {
                     //show error
                   }
           });                  

         } else {
           console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
         }
       }, {scope: 'perms'});        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will want to have logout functionality on your page.  Since it's unclear as to how you've implemented your login button, I'll give one example:

Do a server-side 302 redirect the user to `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=YOUR_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

The next= will be the location where the user can click to log into account Y

For your specific needs you can research here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: But how do I enforce that user must authenticate Y and not anything else ? I am finding that it is not possible, I can just verify what account user has authenticated only after he authenticates. For example In you example above, after logout user can login/authenticate X account again instead of Y. I think i will have to check this once the user has authenticated, that he has actually authenticated the account Y and not some other

Comment: You should log in your database who logged in at what time and use that to check to see if they relogged in as X.  If so, then send them to the logout.php directly rather than showing them content.